# Bootstraptable edit row permanently?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am creating table with bootstrap-table.js. My current trouble is every i edit the row data will be vanished after sort the column. How to edit row permanently even if i sort that column?

this is javascript to show the table

```
    $(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        idField: 'name',
        pagination: true,
        search: true,
        url: '/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/',
        columns: [{
            field: 'name',
            sortable: true,
            title: 'Name'
        }, {
            field: 'stargazers_count',
            sortable: true,
            title: 'Stars'
        }, {
            field: 'forks_count',
            sortable: true,
            title: 'Forks'
        }, {
            field: 'description',
            sortable: true,
            title: 'Description'
        }],
        onPostBody: function () {
            $('#table').editableTableWidget({editor: $('<textarea>')});
        }
    });
});
```

here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dyaskur/vxbfzke5/

by the way my current project is using bootstrap-table not datatable.
I am not try to find solution to save data to database, but save data to bootstrap-table so it can be sorted dynamically

Answer (score -1):

you need to save your editable data then you apply to sort. when you edit your table it's temporary when you sort your table so plugin fetch you stored data and sort them.

```
$(function () {
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    idField: 'name',
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    url: '/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/',
    columns: [{
        field: 'name',
        sortable: true,
        title: 'Name'
    }, {
        field: 'stargazers_count',
        sortable: true,
        title: 'Stars'
    }, {
        field: 'forks_count',
        sortable: true,
        title: 'Forks'
    }, {
        field: 'description',
        sortable: true,
        title: 'Description'
    }],
    onPostBody: function () {
        $('#table').editableTableWidget({editor: $('<textarea>')});
    }
});

$('table td').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
    // do something with the new cell value 
    if (....) { 
        return false; // reject change
    }
});
});
```

Comment: check your plugin event deeply

Comment: hmmm,, i dont get it

Comment: check bootstrap table event's

Comment: what i must doing at there?

Comment: where i must check? no update in jsfiddle. or you folked it?

Comment: you can save data when table td changed

Comment: i am not find solution to save data to database, but save data to bootstrap-table so it can be sorted

Comment: so you can without bootstrap plugin make own sorting code.

Comment: i mean bootstrap-table dynamic sort function.